# setInterval + Random Number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function which generates a number every 5 seconds but there is one problem when I use these function because I want to have `animateNumber()` function on this number. I'm getting this error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

The loop is working just don't know how to fix this error. Thanks for any help

```js
function myInterval() {
    var x = Math.round(Math.random() * 5000) + 1;
}

var timeoutId = setTimeout(ref, 100);
var intervalId = setInterval(ref, 5000);
var intervalId = setInterval(myInterval, 5000);

// ANIMATED NUMBER

function ref() {
    $("#budget-left").animateNumbers(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` variable is defined in the `myInterval` function, so is inaccessible inside `ref()` - hence the error. You need to raise it's scope:

```
var x = 0;

function myInterval() {
    x = Math.round(Math.random() * 5000) + 1;
}

var timeoutId = setTimeout(ref, 100);
var intervalId = setInterval(ref, 5000);
var intervalId = setInterval(myInterval, 5000);

// ANIMATED NUMBER

function ref() {
    $("#budget-left").animateNumbers(x);
}
```

Also note that the logic would make more sense if you had a single timer, calling a single function which both generates the number and then displays it. Try this:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 5000) + 1;
    $("#budget-left").animateNumbers(randomNumber);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Scoping is the issue.

```
        var x =0;
  function myInterval() {
    x = Math.round(Math.random() * 5000) + 1;
    }

    var timeoutId = setTimeout(ref, 100);
    var intervalId = setInterval(ref, 5000);
    var intervalId = setInterval(myInterval, 5000);

    // ANIMATED NUMBER

    function ref() {
        $("#budget-left").animateNumbers(x);
    }
```